Quantstats No module named 'scipy.stats._boost.nct_ufunc'
I tried to start learning about quantstats but when I run something as simple as
import quantstats as qs

stock = qs.utils.download_returns('FB')
print(stock)

I got an Module Error which says

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.stats._boost.nct_ufunc'

I don't really understand how to fix it because I had installed quantstats, scipy and all its dependences. The same message occurs either I use VSCode or PyCharm.
Also, I'm Using Python 3.9.5, I tried the most recent version but also failed.
Does someone know anything about it?
Run example
I expected something like from this tutorial on YouTube:
Expected result
you can also watch it in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dm8GaSYZPF8
at minute 6:40
I really expected some kind of matrix or dataframe as a result

Can you provide the traceback of this error?

The tutorial is from 2021.  I don't know anything about the module you are using, but if anything it is out of date.  Anything in the tutorial - or comments - about versions that it's using or what doesn't work?

quantstats dates from mid 2023.  You could check its issues and pull requests.

I have no problem finding this nct_ufunc in scipy 1.10, and it appears to still be present in the online 1.13 version.

always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

maybe first check if you can import scipy, next import scipy.stats, etc. But I think underscore in name _boots may suggest that it loads some C/C++ library - and it may need to install this C/C++ library separately.

maybe check version print( scipy.__version__ ) - maybe you have old version which may not have this function.

@furas, from the error image it's clear this is a problrm with quatstats, not anything he is doing. scipy shouldn't require any special instalation.  A very old scipy version might be the problem.  My version isn't particularly new (1.10), but I haven't tested quantstats.

@hpaulj maybe error shows problem in quatstats but this problem is to use scipy  - No module named 'scipy.stats._boost.nct_ufunc' - so I proposed to check it step by step - first import scipy and scipy.__version__ , next import scipy.stats, etc. Especially scipy.__version__  can be useful :) As for installing external modules - it was only suggestion (because C/C++ has library boost) but later I checked source code - so you are right it doesn't use external module :) But now we have to wait for OP information about scipy.__version__  :/

I have recently started getting this error because McAfee has quarantined nct_ufunc. So, now I have to determine if McAfee is overreacting or is there really malware in \scipy\stats_boost DLL

Same thing happened to me and it turned out McAfee had quarantined the file. I got the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.stats._boost.nct_ufunc' message.
If you look in the package directory you can see if the file is present. For me this is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\Lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_boost. You may notice an alternation of '.a' files and '.pyd' files, with the file nct_ufunc.cp39-win_amd64.pyd file missing.
You can get the file back by (force) reinstalling scipy.stats, or by having McAfee release it from quarantine.
